# Maven Version Issues

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to test a maven project but i keep getting this error...any ideas?
My Java version is "1.7.0_80"
All suggestions are welcomed..

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -Dmaven.home=/usr/share/maven2 -Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/maven2/bin/m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7541 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/opt/idea/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/share/maven2/boot/classworlds.jar:/opt/idea/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=13.1.4 --no-plugin-registry test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.rancard.kudi:kudi-client:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.glassfish.jersey:project

Reason: Invalid JDK version in profile 'jdk1.7+': Unbounded range: [1.7, for project org.glassfish.jersey:project


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 30 12:42:53 GMT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/172M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the result when I build from the command line...it flags the same error...

```
rancard@RSL-PROD-INT1 ~/IdeaProjects/kudi/client $ mvn package 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - com.rancard.kudi:kudi-client:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]    task-segment: [package]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.glassfish.jersey:project

Reason: Invalid JDK version in profile 'jdk1.7+': Unbounded range: [1.7, for project org.glassfish.jersey:project


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 30 15:35:39 GMT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/108M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the content of my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>kudi-platform</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.rancard.kudi</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>kudi-client</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rancard.kudi</groupId>
            <artifactId>kudi-domain</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-ri</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>   
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What is your JAVA_HOME value ?

Comment: Can you please post your pom.xml ?

Comment: First have you tried it on command line without IDE etc. just plain command line ...I have you don't use Maven 2.X ?

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME                                                                    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

Comment: @khmarbaise yes i have...i use Maven 3.3

Comment: Please try your build on command line and within IDE...

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the pom of the glassfish jersey dependency has a profile that is activated when a certain jdk version is used. But the declaration of the JDK version is malformed.

See below : (http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/project/2.19/project-2.19.pom)

```
<profile>
    <id>jdk1.7+</id>
    <activation>
        <jdk>[1.7,</jdk>
    </activation>
...
</profile>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when maven 2.0.6 was installed.
Run mvn -version and check you have the right maven version, it should look like this:
    Apache Maven 3.0.4
    Maven home: /usr/share/maven